# Can I use a Terminal as the Graphical Console for a VM in with Virt-Manager/Qemu?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I am doing a System V install in Virt-Manager (nothing spectacular) it works great on its own, and I have no retro hardware. The installer is a i386 floppy image, but sadly I don't have a 500 MB HDD, to attempt to install it on hardware (it won't boot with an drives larger than that.)

**But I thought it would be fun to find a way to redirect the output of the VM to `cool-retro-term`.**

I don't feel very comfortable with interfacing with QEMU directly over the Terminal yet, so I was curious if there was a way to do this directly with Virtual manager?

Edit: To be extra clear, rather than relying on KVM just to interface with a TTY through a virtual manitor, I want to use a terminal to interface with said TTY.
As if the terminal were the head.
Something similar to this: [Using Virsh Console](https://ravada.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/config_console.html)

Comment: What do you mean "Terminal as Graphical console"? I know that virtual machines can provide a virtual graphical console. Is this what you need?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I have updated the question to be even more clear

Answer (score 1):

Usually the limitation is partition size and location, not the hard-disk size.
So create a small partition at the start of a large disk (this used to work for this type of OS, when there were no other incompatibilities)

However there may still be many other reasons that it won't work. And be careful not to destroy valuable data, if using direct hardware.